# How to keep implementation/maintenance costs low in Pro*C?

Tags: c++, c, oracle, oracle-pro-c

Having experienced the horror that is Oracle Pro*C, when dealing with dynamically specified columns, and the need for bulk operations (ANSI METHOD 4), I simply must ask:

What Ideas/Techniques can you share which makes it easier to develop/test/debug/maintain C and C++ CRUD applications which use Pro*C or Pro*C++?   I am specifically interested in the Pro*C aspects.

Comment: Ugh.  Thanks for bringing back *those* memories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Pull as much of the Oracle stuff out of the C code as you can and stick it in database PL/SQL packages/procedures/functions.
- Isolate (to the extent possible) the Oracle functionality in your C code. The less scattered your oracle calls are around your C code the better. Even better, have a library/DLL that contains the Oracle-specific stuff.

Oh, and don't forget to sacrifice a goat on the altar at midnight...

Comment: Does it have to be an unblemished goat?

Comment: the goat just needs to be bound at runtime to avoid overloading the shared pool :)

Comment: Plus when it's bound it *can't* run, making the sacrifice that much easier.